# Closed unit ball of $B(H)$ with wot topology is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, topological-vector-spaces

The following is a Theorem of Conway's operator theory:[image]
[image]

I can not understand how he proves it. I think $\phi(\text{ ball B(H)})$ is compact if $\phi(\text{ ball B(H)})$ is closed subset of compact set $X$, but why is $X$ compact?

Comment: $X$ is compact by Tychonov's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Tychonoff's theorem in general point-set topology states that an arbitrary product of compact topological spaces, endowed with the product topology, is again compact. Since the unit ball in a Hilbert space is weakly compact, $X$ becomes compact. Your conclusion is correct I believe.