# Is every weakly closed bounded convex set of $B(H)$ is weakly compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Is every  weakly closed bounded convex set of $B(H)$ is weakly compact? I saw that in many papers, and I don't know why they concluded the weak compactness. e.g. [Page 382](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/258/chp%253A10.1007%252FBFb0058555.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fchapter%2F10.1007%2FBFb0058555&token2=exp=1483916780~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F258%2Fchp%25253A10.1007%25252FBFb0058555.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Fchapter%252F10.1007%252FBFb0058555*~hmac=bc79cbd77955a2d04b36a70df8fbe5b9c616c48adf119b621a8d13e4bfb2677e) .

Comment: What is $H$? To what weak topology on $B(H)$ do you refer? With respect to the weak topology of $B(H)$ as a Banach space, or to the weak operator topology?

Comment: If you refer to a Hilbert space $H$ and the weak operator topology, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092119/closed-unit-ball-of-bh-with-wot-topology-is-compact

Comment: @martini not WOT, I meant Weak Banach topology. I know the unit ball of B(H) is WOT compact, however, in these papers, they must use Weak topology (not necessarily Banach, could be the weak topology of semi-norms). I am totally confused.

Comment: As far as I see it, the author refers to the WOT by "weak topology". First, otherwise $B_{B(H)}$ is not weakly compact, and second: In the introduction he writes "ultraweak, weak, strong and ultrastrong", this for me only makes sense if he is refering to the WOT with "weak topology".

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123678900290?np=y    However, in this paper, theorem 5.1. The author also refers to the reference I gave above. But in this paper, the author used Ryll-Nardzewski theorem, which requires Weak topology rather than WOT. @martini

Comment: Also, in a paper published in DUKE MATH J, I also saw that the authors used Ryll-Nardzewski theorem in a WOT compact set. @martini   http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077307046  section 7.4